# Update variable using Dash slider

Tags: python-3.x

I have a program that uses variables as part of calculations that are applied to dataframes to create a forecast. I'm now trying to display the results in a Dash dashboard and I want users to be able to change the values of the variables using sliders in the dashboard. The chart and slider are showing as I want them to but when I move the slider up and down it doesn't make any change to the chart so I think it's the function definition I'm struggling with.

```
app = JupyterDash('EmissionIntensity')

app.layout = html.Div(children=[dcc.Graph(id='NB_lineFig',figure=NB_lineFig),dcc.Slider(id='value_slider',min=(elec_COP/2),max=(elec_COP*2),value=elec_COP,step=0.4,vertical=False)])

@app.callback(Output(component_id='NB_lineFig',component_property='figure'),Input(component_id='value_slider',component_property='value'))

def useSlider(elec_COP_slider):
    NB_AbsCO2TonnesCopy = NB_AbsCO2Tonnes.copy(deep=True)
    elec_COP_slider = NB_AbsCO2TonnesCopy * elec_COP_slider
    return elec_COP_slider
```